# create AGIScript in classLibrary project

Tags: c#, agi, asternet

I have a simple project create with `c#` (`.Net Core 6.0`)

I create a `AGIScript` class with `Asternet` and recieve the data from `asterisk` server.

it's working well, As long as both are in the same project (`exe` project).

```
public void ListenToAgi()
{
    var agi = new AsteriskFastAGI();
    
    agi.MappingStrategy = new GeneralMappingStrategy(new List<ScriptMapping>()
    {
            new ScriptMapping() {
            ScriptClass = "HI.agiSample.MyAgi",
            ScriptName = "getvariable"
            }
     });
     agi.Start();
}
```

`MyAgi` class is:

```
using AsterNET.NetStandard.FastAGI;

namespace HI.agiSample
{
    public class MyAgi : AGIScript
    {
        public override void Service(AGIRequest request, AGIChannel channel)
        {
            string result = GetVariable("result");
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is, when I move the `MyAgi` class to `ClassLibrary` project, it doesn’t work; the AGI listener doesn’t start listening. But if both classes are in the same project (`exe`), it's working well.

**NOTES:**

1. `namespace` is same in both project , Only the `assembly` name is different.
2. `Project A` is `windows desktop` application and `Project B` is `ClassLibrary`.

Comment: Maybe you should try doing something with your try/catch clause instead of just ignoring the exceptions? Seems like that would be step #1.

Comment: thanks @miken32, the problem is that The flow of the program does not reach to `MyAgi` class. (I removed Try/catch.)

Comment: So sounds like nothing to do with Asterisk then, just a C# compilation issue.

Comment: @miken32و Exactly

Comment: Does your `ProjectA` folder has a reference to `ProjectB`? Like in ProjectA.csproj, is there an item similar to this:
```
<ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\ProjectB\ProjectB.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: @Scott Hsieh, thanks for reply, yes project `B` refrenced to project `A`.

Answer (score -1):

One possible reason why your AGI listener is not working when you move the MyAgi class to a ClassLibrary project is because the AGI listener is instantiated and started in the executable project (Project A), but the MyAgi class is now in a separate ClassLibrary project (Project B).

```
When you move the MyAgi class to a ClassLibrary project, you need to make sure that the executable project (Project A) is still referencing the ClassLibrary project (Project B) and that the AGI listener is being instantiated and started from the executable project (Project A).

Here are some steps you can try:

Make sure that the ClassLibrary project (Project B) is referenced by the executable project (Project A). To do this, right-click on the References node in the Solution Explorer for Project A, and select "Add Reference". Then, select the ClassLibrary project (Project B) from the list of projects.

Make sure that the MyAgi class in the ClassLibrary project (Project B) has the same namespace and assembly name as the executable project (Project A).

In the executable project (Project A), make sure that you are instantiating the AGI listener from the ClassLibrary project (Project B). For example, if the ClassLibrary project (Project B) is named "MyLibrary", you would need to change your code to something like this:


var agi = new AsteriskFastAGI();
    
agi.MappingStrategy = new GeneralMappingStrategy(new List<ScriptMapping>()
{
    new ScriptMapping() {
        ScriptClass = "MyLibrary.MyAgi",
        ScriptName = "getvariable"
    }
});
agi.Start();
```

By specifying the full namespace of the MyAgi class in the ClassLibrary project (Project B), you should be able to instantiate the AGI listener from the executable project (Project A) and still have access to the MyAgi class in the ClassLibrary project (Project B).

I hope this helps you get your AGI listener working again!

Comment: All your solutions have already been done. Please test your solutions before submitting.